# How can I regulate the voltage of a Li-ion battery with the least drop out voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, lithium-ion

I have a one of these:

[image: Li-ion-3.7V-4000mAh]

descriptions:

- full charge voltage : 4.2V
- cut off discharge voltage : 2.75V
- capacity : 4000mAh
- size : 18650

And I want to get 3.3V from it.

but the problem is I can't use regulators (such as AMS1117) because the drop out voltage of it is 1.1V and I should have a 3.3V + 1.1V  = 4.4V at the input. And its impossible for my battery.

**What should I do to have 3.3V until the battery discharges to 3.3V ?**

Comment: What current/range of current does your 3.3V load need?

Comment: Less than 500mA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a buck boost regulator - it would continue to produce 3.3 volts all the way down from probably over 5 volts to possibly 2.5 volts. Obviously you have to ensure that the Lithium battery doesn't sink too low or it will become damaged but that's another problem that is solved by using a comparator and a regulator shut-down circuit. Here's an idea: -

[image]

Or....

[image]

Or...

[image]

Or maybe try using their search engine [here](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Buck-Boost_Regulator#!1646_Buck-Boost|SEPIC!1032_<=2.5!1033_>=5!1105_<=3.3!1034_>=3.3!1035_3.85:19.3!1107_1:5!2086_>8.3!vinmin_2.5!vinmax_5!vout_3.3!iout_1!vout2_!iout2_!vout3_!iout3_)

Comment: Thank you. But none of those ICs are available in my location.

Comment: Try texas instruments - they have a decent portfolio of switching regulators.

Comment: Can I use a 3.3V zaner diode ?

Comment: What would happen if you connected your battery (at 4.2 volts) to a zener diode of 3.3 volts - smoke!

Comment: @BlueSky You have to say to Andy all things that you need. I know that what do you need then I'm going to say to Andy...

Comment: @Andyaka Hey Andy, the Blue Sky is from Iran like me and we are in sanctions then we cannot to buy all things that you provide to us. in fact, he just need a passive circuit. your answer will be helpful and useful to him if you provide a passive circuit.

Comment: @roh the best method is buck-boost and I believe this is the best answer. Sanctions are problematic but designing a buck boost circuit with components you can obtain is still the better method.

Comment: @Roh you helped me much in this forum. Yes I want a passive circuit. It can also have a micro controller like ATtiny13 **as a switch**.

Comment: @AHB Why don't you try Zener diode as voltage regulator. For 3.3V ?

Comment: @Raj dissipation. And its not reliable for a circuit with variable current sink.